# Shellcode in C program

Tags: c, shellcode

In [Demystifying the Execve Shellcode](http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/04/demystifying-execve-shellcode-stack.html) is explained a way to write an execve shellcode:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned char code[] = 
"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";

main()
{

    printf("Shellcode Length: %d\n", strlen(code));

    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;

    ret();
}
```

What does the line `int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;` do?

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) says: cast code into pointer to function returning int

Comment: i don't understand the () after *ret and int(*)() before code.

Comment: To be able to parse such constructions in the head, go through clockwise/spiral rule: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: Btw: this approach is disabled by default on W^X OSes.  Running `nop (0x90)` on an 64-bit OS X on a modern processor, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because the kernel won't run any code from .bss, .text or the heap because these areas refert o PAE/long mode page table entries with bit 63 set (NX).  It might work on a non-PAE/non-long-mode OS without something like PAX/ExecShield in something ancient, like DOS.  Writing to code areas also won't work (self-mutating over a bunch of C inline asm `nop`s).  Better to make a program which spits out a minimal executable for the given platform(s) and run that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
  int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        1              2

  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               3
```

1. It defines `ret` as a pointer to a function which has no parameter `()` and returns `int`. So, Those `()` indicates the definition of parameters of a function.
2. It's for casting `code` to a pointer to a function which has no parameter `()` and returns `int`.
3. Casts `code` as a function and assigns it to `ret`. After that you can call `ret();`.

```
unsigned char code[] =  "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\...
```

It is a sequence of machine instructions represented by hex values. It will be injected to the code as a function.

Comment: So, when ret() is called, how does the code actually "run", since i see do not seen C call that "loads" the shellcode and runs it?

Comment: @user85030, yes, "load" is called in `ret()`, google for "pointer to function"

Comment: The [link](http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/04/demystifying-execve-shellcode-stack.html) you've provided is explaining it in 11 steps. That machine instruction sequence is doing everything as same as a call process needs.

Comment: Okay. So i read about function pointers and understood part 1). Can part 2) be written as (int* ())code instead of (int(*)())code? To rephrase my question, how is a variable casted into a function? (Since we have a function pointer on the left being assigned to the function on the right.

Comment: You can not use `(int* ())` because it's not the way to declare pointer to function. Think about addresses, in C all objects have addresses, it just casts the address of `code` as the address of a function.

Comment: What does (star) in int(*)() signify? I understand that int is the return type and () means a function without any parameters.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can this function pointer part be avoided to get the same result? i.e. can it be re-written in a different form?

Comment: In C++ there are many different ways, but in C this is common way (maybe the only way)

Comment: @MM. Thanks a lot for your help. Can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632639/re-writing-a-small-execve-shellcode ?

Answer (score 2):

```
    (*(void(*)())shellcode)()
```

==

```
    p = (void(*)()) shellcode;
    (*p)();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can this function pointer part be re-written in a simpler form?

I don't know if you think this is simpler, but maybe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char code[] = 
"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";

typedef int(*shellcode_t)();

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("Shellcode Length: %ld\n", strlen(code));

    shellcode_t ret = (shellcode_t)code;

    ret();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The int line declares the ret() function, by pointing to the code[] array; in other words, the function is mapped to the code[] binary instructions.

The \x construct is a safe way to embed hexadecimal characters in a string.  You could for instance replace “\x31” by “1” as the character code of “1” is 49, or hexadecimal 31.

Comment: i don't understand the () after *ret and int(*)() before code.

Comment: `ret` is a function pointer(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) to a function with an undefined number of arguments(`()`) that returns a `int`. `(int(*) () )` It's casting `code` function-address to make according to funtion-pointer address that take undefined number of arguments,that's how `ret` is declared.

Comment: Can this function pointer part be re-written in a simpler form?