# Executing Byte Array in Go

Tags: go, function-pointers, shellcode

I'm trying to execute shellcode within a Go program, similar to how you can do it with other languages.

Example 1 - [Shellcode in C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626857/shellcode-in-c-program)

Example 2 - http://www.debasish.in/2012/04/execute-shellcode-using-python.html

All methods have broadly similar techniques - assign the shellcode to executable memory via the OS specific allocation (mmap, virtualalloc, etc) and then execute the code by creating a function pointer pointing to that location before executing.

Here is my horrible hacky example at performing the same thing in Go. The shellcode has manipulations performed on it before being passed to the function, so it's format as a []byte is fixed. Saying that mmap expects a file descriptor passed in which is why the horrible "writing to a tmp file" section exists.

```
func osxExec(shellcode []byte) {
    f, err := os.Create("data/shellcode.tmp")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    _,_ = f.Write(shellcode)
    f.Sync()

    b, err := syscall.Mmap(int(f.Fd()), 0, len(shellcode), syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_WRITE|syscall.PROT_EXEC, syscall.MAP_SHARED)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%p", b)
}
```

At the end of the code I've got a pointer (slice?) to the code in what I presume is executable memory - but I've got no idea how to cast this address into a function pointer for execution. I asked on some IRC channels but it was suggested that it may not be possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: If you're writing it to a file you might as well call syscall.Exec on it

Comment: @ReyCharles, that would imply writing a properly formatted file (like ELF on Linux, PE on Windows etc). Not sure if Windows still allows running MS-DOS COM-formatted files (which were dead-simple).

Comment: Yea, sorry, I wasn't thinking :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, though I have not tested them myself.

You may want to have a look at https://github.com/nelhage/gojit/blob/master/jit.go
It implements a solution based on cgo (which is safer, but slower), and a solution based on a direct call. Look at all the build related functions.

Comment: Thank you - that's an awesome library which worked perfectly.

Comment: @Peleus : and if cgo is disabled ?

Answer (score 6):

First, you don't need to (currently) use `mmap` at all, since go memory is executable. If you do need `mmap`, you can use anonymous memory and forgo the temp file:

```
b, e := syscall.Mmap(0, 0, len(shellcode), syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_WRITE|syscall.PROT_EXEC, syscall.MAP_ANON)
copy(b, shellcode)
```

Otherwise, you can try to use `shellcode` directly, since it's already backed by a contiguous array.

As for converting the bytes in `shellcode` to a function, the analog from C would look like:

```
f := *(*func() int)(unsafe.Pointer(&d[0]))
```

which creates a function value named `f` which can then be called like a normal function.

If the shellcode isn't specifically crafted fro Go, and you need to call it from a C stack, it would be easier to do it directly in C using cgo.

```
/*
call(char *code) {
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
}
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    ...
    // at your call site, you can send the shellcode directly to the C 
    // function by converting it to a pointer of the correct type.
    C.call((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&shellcode[0])))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I marked the above as correct since it allowed a slightly simpler solution - however I appreciate that what you wrote also taught me some other techniques for which I'm appreciative of. Upvoted.

Comment: @JimB : thank you for you short answer. But how to do that kind of thing without the`C`package ? I mean with cgo disabled ?

Comment: @user2284570: I'm not sure if that's possible. All Go programs are multi-threaded, and it may require the runtime hooks used by cgo to safely enter non-go code.

Comment: @JimB : and what if the`unsafe`package isn’t installed ?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to learn how `mmap` `PROT_EXEC` would work in `Go`, and came up with the same problem.

I had a hard time to get the `[]byte` to be casted to a function correctly. It is not so obvious as some of the answers here state.

I've came up with an working example of how to do it using a higher level `mmap` library called [mmap-go](https://github.com/edsrzf/mmap-go). In this example we have an executable code of a function that increments one to the passed argument.

```
code := []byte{
    0x48, 0xc7, 0x44, 0x24, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x48, 0x8b, 0x44, 0x24, 0x08,
    0x48, 0xff, 0xc0,
    0x48, 0x89, 0x44, 0x24, 0x10,
    0xc3,
}

memory, err := mmap.MapRegion(nil, len(code), mmap.EXEC|mmap.RDWR, mmap.ANON, 0)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

copy(memory, code)

memory_ptr := &memory
ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&memory_ptr)
f := *(*func(int) int)(ptr)

fmt.Println(f(10)) // Prints 11
```

I thought `unsafe.Pointer(&memory[0])` would solve my problem like one of the answers suggests. But by doing that you cannot cast the address to a callable function in the correct address. The trick was to go one step further and do this

```
memory_ptr := &memory
ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&memory_ptr)
```

instead of

```
f := *(*func(int) int)(&memory[0])
```

Comment: That's a great solution! However, I noticed when using your approach that randomly (1 of 5 runs) the program does not run the f function correctly and instead throws "Exception 0xc00000fd 0x0 0xdc1c003000 0x7ffbb0ab1fe7
PC=0x7ffbb0ab1fe7

runtime: unknown pc"

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Seems to be aslr related. Disabling it helps