# Segfault when running hello world shellcode in C program

Tags: exploit, shellcode, assembly, x86

sorry if this question sounds dumb but I am very new to shellcoding and I was trying to get a hello world example to work on a 32 bit linux machine.

As this is shellcoding, I used a few tricks to remove null bytes and shorten the code. Here it is:

```
section .data

section .text
global _start
_start:

;Instead of xor eax,eax
;mov al,0x4
push byte 0x4
pop eax
;xor ebx,ebx
push byte 0x1
pop ebx
;xor ecx,ecx
cdq ; instead of xor edx,edx

;mov al, 0x4
;mov bl, 0x1
mov dl, 0x8
push 0x65726568
push 0x74206948
;mov ecx, esp
push esp
pop ecx
int 0x80

mov al, 0x1
xor ebx,ebx
int 0x80
```

This code works fine when I compile and link it with the following commands:

```
$ nasm -f elf print4.asm
$ ld -o print4 -m elf_i386 print4.o
```

However, I tried running it within the following C code:
    $ cat shellcodetest.c
    #include 
    #include

```
char *shellcode = "\x04\x6a\x58\x66\x01\x6a\x5b\x66\x99\x66\x08\xb2\x68\x68\x68\x65\x69\x48\x54\x66\x59\x66\x80\xcd\x01\xb0\x31\x66\xcd\xdb\x80";

int main(void) {
    ( *( void(*)() ) shellcode)();
}
$ gcc shellcodetest.c –m32 –z execstack -o shellcodetest
$ ./shellcodetest
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Could someone please explain what is happening there? I tried running the code in gdb and noticed something weird happening with esp. But as I said before, I still lack experience to really understand what is going on here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're executing the pointer value as code, not the string literal it points to.  Use `const char shellcode[] = "..."`.  It has to be `const` so it goes in the `.rodata` section, which goes in the text segment (read+execute), not the `.data` section (data segment = read+write).

Comment: Hey there, correct me if I'm wrong but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626857/shellcode-in-c-program) explains that the byte code is actually cast to a pointer to a function with no parameter (). So I think the hexadecimal string ends up in the .text section which is AX. Moreover, LarsH managed to run the shellcode in the C program just by changing the endianness (I feel so noob for not seeing that...).

Comment: Yeah, my comment was wrong.  `shellcode` in C loads the pointer from memory when you write `char *shellcode`, and the pointed-to string literal itself is in `.rodata`.  It would save a level of indirection to use `const char shellcode[]`, though:  `call eax` (or even `call rel32`) instead of `call [absolute_address_of_pointer]`.  (And `char shellcode[]` (not const) would crash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shellcode does not work, because it is not entered in the correct endianness. You did not state how you extracted the bytes from the file `print4`, but both `objdump` and `xxd` gives the bytes in correct order.

```
$ xxd print4 | grep -A1 here
0000060: 6a04 586a 015b 99b2 0868 6865 7265 6848  j.Xj.[...hherehH
0000070: 6920 7454 59cd 80b0 0131 dbcd 8000 2e73  i tTY....1.....s
$ objdump -d print4

print4:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048060 <_start>:
 8048060:       6a 04                   push   $0x4
 8048062:       58                      pop    %eax
 8048063:       6a 01                   push   $0x1
...
```

The changes you need to do is to swap the byte order, '\x04\x6a' -> '\x6a\x04'.
When I run your code with this change, it works!

```
$ cat shellcodetest.c
char *shellcode = "\x6a\x04\x58\x6a\x01\x5b\x99\xb2\x08\x68\x68\x65\x72\x65\x68\x48\x69\x20\x74\x54\x59\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80";
int main(void) {
        ( *( void(*)() ) shellcode)();
}
$ gcc shellcodetest.c -m32 -z execstack -o shellcodetest
$ ./shellcodetest
Hi there$
```